# Cloud Dataflow Job stuck with Checking permissions granted to controller Service Account

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

ia m running a cloud dataflow job which is supposed to write data to one of my project's bucket
The job seems stuck in with the following message

Checking permissions granted to controller Service Account

I can't figure out why is this as the bucket belong to my project.

could anyone help?
kind regards
 Marco

Answer (score 1):

Your job is stuck in a phase where the Cloud Dataflow service connects to Identity and Access Management (IAM) service to validate permissions for starting worker VMs. A hang here would typically indicate an outage in Google's infrastructure, but I don't see any [problems reported](https://status.cloud.google.com/) (there was an [outage yesterday](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/zall/20005)). If there was a permission error you should have gotten a log message to indicate that. If there are further log messages, please update your post to include those? If not, you'll need to file a customer support ticket with Google.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I am thinking problem is actually somewhere in my job.I have other jobs which do simillar thing - though not exacty the same - which works fine. will need to debug further. By the way, how do  i fill a customer support ticket  given the fact i have the lowest package on cloud? i suppose i have to go to forums...

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to file a support ticket without a paid support package. There should be some additional log messages after the one you posted to indicate what has gone wrong. With the bucket (both temporary and output) being in the same project as your job, you shouldn't be having problems. You might double check to ensure all the service accounts and permissions are set correctly: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#security_and_permissions_for_pipelines_on_google_cloud_platform

Comment: Hello Andrew i managed to get my workflow to write to a bucket by replacing some logic which involved pandas dataframes and some external libaries. (pandas-datareader). i am speculating perhaps some issues either with serlization or with dealing with pandas or pandas-datareader. I didnt get any extra error message despite my logging....  You aware of anything like this? i will spend some time scaling down my job and investigating what's going on. thanks

Comment: Interesting! There must be more logs to your job that you may have filtered out, as the log message posted here occurs before any user code is launched. (There should be a message immediately following it about starting worker VMs.) Dataflow executes arbitrary user code, so without knowing how you are processing data or writing to buckets it is difficult to know what is going on. If you end up with an isolated example that would make it easier to debug.